# Parallel.ForEach does not update shared variable

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Having the folloing code, how can I update shared variable?

```
     List<Person> list = new List<Person> {new Person {Age = 1}, new Person {Age = 2}, new Person {Age = 5}};
        long total = 0;

        Parallel.ForEach(list, () => 0, (person, loop, subtotal) =>
            {
                Add(person, subtotal);
                return subtotal;
            },

            finalResult => Interlocked.Add(ref total, finalResult)
        );

    public static void Add(Person person, int shared)
    {
        // Do some work
        shared =+ person.Age;
    }
```

For some reason shared comes back as 0.

Comment: this is not going to work, even when you fix the `ref subtotal` problem.  You have a very obvious race condition. You are updating and reading a value constantly.

Comment: How can I keep track of a shared variable then?

Comment: @BobSwanson Don't parallelize the sum in the first place.  It'll be much slower than just summing the values in a single thread.  In addition to being much faster, it'll also be simpler, less error prone, more maintainable, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared comes back as 0, because it was sent in as 0 and was passed by value. You need to use the [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword, or address this behavior in some other way(static variable).

```
public static void Add(Person person, ref int shared)
{
    // Do some work
    shared =+ person.Age;
}
```

It looks like you also have an issue where you're using '= +' in place of '+='.

```
public static void Add(Person person, ref int shared)
{
    // You likely meant to do this.
    shared += person.Age;
}
```

Comment: Presumably you intend to use +=? As is you're setting shared to the positive value of Age?

Comment: ahh, that worked, does it need Lock? since it's shared?

Answer (score 3):

Changing a bit your code, you will the expected result:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Age = 1 },
        new Person { Age = 2 },
        new Person { Age = 5 }
    };

    long total = 0;

    Parallel.ForEach(persons, person => Add(person, ref total));

    Console.WriteLine(total);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void Add(Person person, ref long shared)
{
    // since here you access a shared variabe, we
    // can use the Interlocked class in order our operation
    // to be atomic. 
    Interlocked.Add(ref shared, person.Age);
}
```

Comment: If my shared were not an int or long, but a decimal, would i use lock() instead?

Comment: @BobSwanson Exactly :)

Comment: Is there any way of doing the method "Add" async? I mean with await inside? Thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidCon As far as I know, we don't have such an opportunity. `Interlocked` class does not provide any `async` methods. You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Same reason it wouldn't work in "regular" C# code... integers are value types, so you need to make the parameter a ref parameter. Otherwise, you are just incrementing the local copy. Also, you should use Interlocked.Increment instead of += or you might run into threading issues since += is not necessarily atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int sum = list.AsParallel().Sum(person => person.Age);
```

the result will be the same and less code will be used.